# Border-radius causes weird behaviour in IE9, IE10 and IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, css, internet-explorer-11

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvZCq/) produces expected results in real browsers (I tried FF, GC, Safari), but breaks unexpectedly in IE9, IE10 and IE11. No problems with IE7 or IE8.

[image: Firefox is on the left and IE9-IE11 is on the right]

```html
<div class="root">
    Top
    <div class="footer">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

```css
.root {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: 25px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

If I remove `border-radius` or `overflow:hidden` from parent, everything works fine. But what on Earth does it have to do with fixed position child? It is supposed to be always positioned relatively to viewport.

Is it a known\documented bug? What is the rationale behind it?

Comment: Can you describe the expected behavior a little more clearly?

Comment: Left screenshot. Green footer, width is 100% of the screen, height is 100px.

Comment: Very strange indeed. Add `border-radius:30px` to `.footer` and you can see that only the top-left corner is changed--this is because somehow the margin of the `.root` is being inverted and is clipping `.footer` (with rounded corner margin!). So that explains why changing `overflow` affects it, but I have no idea why the presence of `border-radius` breaks it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I think is happening.

Browser vendors seem to have decided that `fixed` position elements that overflow have clipping turned off, e.g. they are **not** clipped by their parents. This makes things consistent, since `fixed` elements are positioned relative to the window, not the parent. If clipping was applied, it would have position/width relative to the **window** and clipping relative to the **parent**. It would *visually look* like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KYP7U/1/) (except the bottom corners should be rounded--more on that below).

So: `fixed` element, no overflow clipping. Check.

But something changed in IE9. They introduced support for rounded corners. Now to what I said about the rounded clipping.  IE9 actually did this right. Many browsers right now will clip with square corners, even when the element has rounded corners. This is bad. Apparently, IE9 fixed this by detecting the presence of rounded corners, and in such cases, *re-drawing the clipping*. When it does that, it makes two mistakes.

1. It applies the clipping--undoing the "`fixed` element, no
   overflow clipping" rule. Clipping is turned back on, and the element
   is now clipped by the width of the parent.
2. The clipping is just put directly on the element,
   un-centered, with no regards to the fact that the clipping is
   supposed to be from the parent. It's just clipped starting at 0,0
   out to the designated width and height--that's why the green element
   appears left aligned--the right/bottom 50px are hidden.

### Fixes?

- Don't nest `fixed` inside `absolute`. (Best solution--avoid weird edge-cases in the future)
- Give the parent (red) div a width.
- Nest a new `div` directly inside `.root` and move the `overflow:hidden` to it. [Fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/uvZCq/4/) (Least intrusive)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue:

```
<div class="relative-parent-with-border-radius">
  ...
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-child">...</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Fixed by setting `.container` position to `-ms-page`